# LUKS + TPM2 + auto unlock at boot (systemd-cryptenroll)

Tags: luks, tpm

Please, help me to finish setup LUKS + TPM2 + auto unlock at boot.

I have installed clean Ubuntu 22.04.2 I have encrypted partition in GUI while installing OS. I have installed all updates.

```
Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
5.19.0-43-generic
systemd 249 (249.11-0ubuntu3.9)
```

I am trying to use this manual: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Trusted_Platform_Module#systemd-cryptenroll

I have installed:

```
tpm2-tools
dracut-core_059-3_amd64.deb
dracut_059-3_all.deb
```

Next:

```
sudo dracut --add tpm2-tss
sudo systemd-cryptenroll --tpm2-device=auto --tpm2-pcrs=0+7 /dev/nvme0n1p3
```

I have added in `/etc/crypttab`:

```
nvme0n1p3_crypt UUID=1fce6364-485c-4524-9c73-7bd4dac5bd32 none luks,discard
```

System still asking for a passphrase while booting.

I am do not understand what I need to do exactly to auto-unlock LUKS via TPM on boot.

Answer (score 6):

This is what I'm using to allow LUKS decryption using TPM2 in the same Ubuntu 22. Not using systemd-cryptenroll, but clevis. The only 'downside' is that it shows the password prompt at boot, but disappears after getting the key from tpm.

```
    #!/bin/bash
    
    #install needed packages
    apt-get -y install clevis clevis-tpm2 clevis-luks clevis-initramfs initramfs-tools tss2
    
    #proceed
    echo -n Enter LUKS password:
    read -s LUKSKEY
    echo ""
    
    clevis luks bind -d /dev/nvme0n1p3 tpm2 '{"pcr_bank":"sha256"}' <<< "$LUKSKEY"
    
    update-initramfs -u -k all
    
    #check
    clevis luks list -d /dev/nvme0n1p3
    
    #delete example; -s is one of the slots reported by the previous command
    #clevis luks unbind -d /dev/nvme0n1p3 -s 1 tpm2
```

No need to modify anything else(not even crypttab file).

Comment: Thank you! I will try it. I have tried to use "build-in" (systems) to unlock LUKS.

Comment: Thank God for you!  This information was so convoluted to find, and this was so succinct and easy, and worked!

Comment: I was worried about the device name `/dev/nvme0n1p3` being hard coded but on my fresh install I had the exact same disk so it worked without modification.